# Picking ID's from a file

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a log file (.txt) which has information as below:

```
Filename1 -  A3332NCDER
Filename2 -  B3332NCDER
Filename3 -  B1222NCDERE
Filename4 -  C1222NCDER
Filename4 -  C1222NCDERE
```

I am writing to the filename and the corresponding ID to the log file as below:

```
using (StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(logFileName, true))
{
    logFile.WriteLine(fileName + "   - " + fileID);
}
```

Later to get the ID's I am doing the below:

```
char[] delimiters = new char[]{'\n','\r','-'};

IList<string> fileIDs = File.ReadAllText(logFileName)
         .Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         .Where((lineItem, index) => index % 2 == 1)
         .Select(lineItem => lineItem.Trim())
         .ToList();
```

Now for each processing I am adding the date and time as below. Also in some cases the id's can be multiple which are separated by comma.

```
*****Files processing done at: 9/16/2011 11:30:48 AM *****
Filename1 -  A3332NCDER
Filename2 -  B3332NCDER
Filename3 -  B1222NCDERE

*****Files processing done at: 9/16/2011 12:10:15 AM *****
Filename4 -  C1222NCDER
Filename4 -  C1222NCDERE,226222105A
```

I need to pick the ID's into IList from the above data ? One way I can think of is to first split by \n and \r then remove empty lines & the lines which contain the date. Then again split by '-' and then add the ID's to list. Is it possible to do it with single linq query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using Linq could be:

```
List<string> ids = File.ReadAllLines(logFile)
     .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)) // Trim empty lines 
     .Where(l => l.StartsWith("Filename"))      // Just get ID lines
     .SelectMany(l => l.Split('-').Skip(1))     // Skip the "FilenameX" section
     .SelectMany(ids => ids.Split(              // Get IDs (+trim)
                    new[]{' ',','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                )  
     .ToList();
```

Comment: `StartsWidth("FileName")` does not look very flexible. Maybe "!StartsWith("*****")` would work better.

Comment: @Jens: It really depends on the file output formatting...  Using my approach has the advantage of ignoring any future additional lines, provided the "real" data is always written using the same pattern.  Either will work for this dataset, though.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good application for regular expressions, depending on how much control you have over the filenames. But then, any approach using "String.Split" does not work with filenames containing dashes either.

The expression

```
(?<=- *|,)[A-Z0-9]+
```

will match every id in your sample data. See it in action [here at ideone](http://ideone.com/qjXvj).

"[A-Z0-9]+" is describing any combination of uppercase letters and digits, and the "(?<=- *|,)" part ensures that this is preceeded by either a dash and some spaces or a comma.